@Import in @Configuration does not import Jpa annotations after Spring Boot 3.3.0
After the update from Spring Boot 3.2.0 to 3.3.0 configuration import do not work properly.
I have a base config class that imports JPA annotations to scan for entities/repositories from external module.
The problem is if I'm running my app with importing config in internal configuration - I'm receiving an error that the app cannot find external entities (declared in JPAConfig)
But if I'm putting my @Import({JpaConfig.class}) annotation to the @SpringBootApplication - it all works properly
Keep in mind, that on Spring Boot 3.2.0 it all worked properly.
I believe, this issue can be caused by changed logic of component scanning in Spring Boot 3.3.0, but on Spring Boot 3.3 Release Notes I didn't find any reference about that, unfortunately.
Can someone give me a hint of what is wrong here?
An Example:
Project structure:
project-root
├── auth-server 
│   ├── pom.xml <-- separate module, an App
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── io
│   │       │       └── auth
│   │       │           ├── domain
│   │       │           │   └── db
│   │       │           │        └── AuthDbEntity.java
│   │       │           ├── MainConfig.java 
│   └───────└───────────└── AuthApp.java 
├── common.  <-- module with common classes/entities, not an app
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── io
│   │       │       └── common
│   │       │           ├── db
│   │       │           │   └── entity
│   │       │           │        └── CommonDbEntity.java
│   └───────└───────────└── JpaConfig.java 
└── pom.xml

project-root/pom.xml
...
 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
...
<modules>
        <module>auth-server</module>
        <module>common</module>
</modules>

project-root/common/.../JpaConfig.java
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"io.common.db.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"io.common.db.repository"})
public class JpaConfig {
}

The error will be in the next scenario:
project-root/auth-server/.../MainConfig.java
@Configuration
@Import({JpaConfig.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.auth.domain.db")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "io.auth.repository")
public class MainConfig {
...
}

project-root/auth-server/.../AuthApp.java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApp {
...
}

The error will not be in the next scenario:
project-root/auth-server/.../MainConfig.java
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.auth.domain.db")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "io.auth.repository")
public class MainConfig {
...
}

project-root/auth-server/.../AuthApp.java
@Import({JpaConfig.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthApp {
...
}


Please provide a complete yet minimal example that reproduces the behavior that you have described
